# Vim: View highlight rules acting on current word/character?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible in vim to see why a particular word is highlighted the way it is? In particular, I have `set spell` on, and it's got some weird highlighting going on in some situations. This is not limited to spellcheck, obviously.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have something like this in my status line:

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

It displays how vim has parsed the syntax for the item under the cursor, which you may be able to use to figure out the source of the highlight.

Comment: That's cool, but it doesn't seem to work for spell check. In a tex file, it results in `texMatcher` for both un-highlighted and spell-check highlighted plain text. It works well for tex commands and other syntax though!